# Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'SendTextMessageAsync' does not exist in the namespace 'Telegram.Bot'

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I want to create InlineKeyBord in telegram bot in c# 
but I have this error:

> CS0234 The type or namespace name 'SendTextMessageAsync' does not exist in the namespace 'Telegram.Bot'

```
var keyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(new [] {
  new [] // 1st row
  {
    new KeyboardButton("1"),
      new KeyboardButton("2"),
  },
  new [] // 2nd row
  {
    new KeyboardButton("3"),
      new KeyboardButton("4"),
  }
});

await Telegram.Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Choose", replyMarkup: keyboard);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
await Telegram.Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Choose", replyMarkup: keyboard);
```

to:

```
// see https://mrroundrobin.github.io/telegram.bot/html/M_Telegram_Bot_TelegramBotClient__ctor.htm
var bot = new Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient(yourtokenhere); 
await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Choose", replyMarkup: keyboard);
```

Comment: i tried this code but i have 2 errors:  1-Error CS0118 'Telegram.Bot' is a namespace but is used like a type.  i had using  telegram.Bot